# Advantage of redis db

Tags: mysql, database, redis

Please explain why redisdb is used   in some cases. which are theese cases which redis db is used? Is redis good for managing big database or something?

Comment: Usually Redis isn't used instead of MySQL but alongside. They have different uses and can be used together in an application. Please see t34t5's answer for what kinds of data are used with Redis.

Answer (score 3):

Redis is an in memory data store. One popular use for Redis is as a state server, saving session information. Redis is supposed to be fast because it works with memory. So, if you used redis to hold session information, you will only hit the
machine's memory. If you used a database like mysql for session state, there is a high likelihood that disk I/O will be required.

Redis doesn't have a strong persistence mechanism and as such should not be used as an application's database.

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7897243/3469752) and [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13645017/3469752) may be relevant.